# What is the meaning of LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS and when to use it?

Tags: java, linkoption

I want to check if a directory is exist by using the notExists(Path path, LinkOption... options) and Im confused with the  LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS although after I googled I still not quite get when to use it. Here are my codes:

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.nio.file.Files; 
import java.nio.file.*; 
import java.util.ArrayList; 

public class Test 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {   
          Path source = Paths.get("Path/Source");
          Path destination = Paths.get("Path/Destination");
          ArrayList<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();
          int retry = 3;

          // get files inside source directory
          files = getFiles(source);

          // move all files inside source directory
          for (int j=0; j < files.size(); j++){
              moveFile(source,destination,files.get(j),retry);         
          }       
    } 

    // move file to destination directory
    public static void moveFile(Path source, Path destination, String file, int retry){
        while (retry>0){
            try {
                // if destination path not exist, create directory
                if (Files.notExists(destination, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS)) {
                    // make directory  
                    Files.createDirectories(destination);  
                }

                // move file to destination path
                Path temp = Files.move(source.resolve(file),destination.resolve(file));         

                // if successfully, break
                if(temp != null){ 
                    break;
                } 
                // else, retry
                else {
                    --retry;
                } 

            } catch (Exception e){
                // retry if error occurs
                --retry;
            }
        }
    }

    // get all file names in source directory
    public static ArrayList<String> getFiles(Path source){

        ArrayList<String> filenames = new ArrayList<String>();
        File folder = new File(source.toString());
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();   // get all files inside the source directory

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                filenames.add(listOfFiles[i].getName()); // add file's name into arraylist
            } 
        }
        return filenames;
    }
}
```

The result of using LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS and not using it are the same (The files are transferred to the destination). So, Im guessing for my case, i can ignore the Link option? also, in what situation will i be needing that? Thanks!

Comment: Post your [mre] demonstrating how you attempted to use it. what class does the `notExists()` method belong to. Then tell us what the result of that code was. That is did the directory exist or not? Did the result change if you used the NOFOLLOW_LINKS option. You can check out: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61785056/131872 which shows how to post an MRE. You can also check out my answer where I decided to use the `NOFOLLOW_LINKS`. It might help explain the difference.

Comment: whoops sorry, already edited the question, Im using **java.nio.file.Files** . The directory has not yet existed, so by using notExists(), I will create the directory when i first run the code. Also, the result for using NOFOLLOW_LINKS and using it is the same...

Answer (score 0):

> So, Im guessing for my case, i can ignore the Link option?

You can only follow a link if the link exists.

So if you are testing to make sure a directory doesn't exist, there are two outcomes.

1. it exists, so there is no need to follow the link.
2. it doesn't exist, so there is nothing to follow.

> in what situation will i be needing that?

Did you look at my answer in the link I provided you? I tried to give a simple example.